# Cousin showed me P__n

Tags: allah

When it was eid-ul-fitr my cousin told me let me show this website so i said ok he told me close my eyes  and then i closed my eyes and opend it was P__n I have repented for it, Will allah forgive me?

Comment: First of all, your cousin "tricked" you into watching something that is extremely haram, and I believe you were not aware of this, so the sin is on your cousin. Also, did you look away from that filth when he showed you, or did you keep watching? You need to know that these things are a grave danger and one should avoid them as much as possible. If you didn't do it intentionally, then Insha' Allah there is nothing on you, and Allah forgives all sins, so repent sincerely and insha' Allah, Allah will forgive you!

Comment: i look away from that filthy things